# Restrict a Qdockwidget to a quadrant rather than Left/Right/Top/Bottom

Tags: python, pyqt4, qdockwidget

I have three main sections of a main window, where the left side (critical data) should take the entire height of the window, while the data on the right should be split between top and bottom. Data in the lower right is related, but not critical - which is why I'd like it to be un-dockable/closable.

The [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-dockwidgets-example.html) shows an example of this in C++, but I have no idea how to turn this into Python code, as I have no C++ experience.

The Qt Designer application limits the user to Left/Right/Top/Bottom, and limiting the maximum width of the widget doesn't allow me to occupy the un-used space (i.e. doesn't allow the list widget on the left to take up the full height of the main window)

Long story short, to get a Qdockwidget into the lower right corner, you have to put another dock widget above it (it's still limited to Right/Left/Top/Bottom DockWidgetArea). After looking at the answer from eyllanesc below, I'll post two solutions. First, a simplified version of his code and then a modified version of the code I originally posted.

Eyllanesc's translation from the C++ example from I mentioned above:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        # Upper table widget
        dock = QtGui.QDockWidget("Upper", self.centralWidget)
        dock.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(dock)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(7)
        for i in range(7):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, item)
            self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(i).setText("Item " + str(i + 1))
        for i in range(6):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, item)
        dock.setWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock)
        # Lower table widget
        dock = QtGui.QDockWidget("Lower", self.centralWidget)
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtGui.QTableWidget(dock)
        self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(7)
        for i in range(7):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget_2.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, item)
        for i in range(6):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, item)
        dock.setWidget(self.tableWidget_2);
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock)
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.listWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        for i in range(10):
            item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
            item = self.listWidget.item(i)
            item.setText("Item " + str(i + 1))
        self.listWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(340, 600))
        self.setWindowTitle("Dock Widgets")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the modified version of the code I originally used:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.listWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        for i in range(10):
            item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
            item = self.listWidget.item(i)
            item.setText("Item " + str(i + 1))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.dockWidget = QtGui.QDockWidget(MainWindow)
        self.dockWidget.setFeatures(QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable)
        self.dockWidget.setObjectName("dockWidget")
        self.dockWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.dockWidgetContents.setObjectName("dockWidgetContents")
        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.dockWidgetContents)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(7)
        for i in range(7):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, item)
            self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(i).setText("Item " + str(i + 1))
        for i in range(6):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, item)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.dockWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.dockWidget.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents)
        MainWindow.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(2), self.dockWidget)
        self.dockWidget_2 = QtGui.QDockWidget(MainWindow)
        self.dockWidget_2.setFeatures(QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetClosable|QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable)
        self.dockWidget_2.setObjectName("dockWidget_2")
        self.dockWidgetContents_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.dockWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("dockWidgetContents_2")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.dockWidgetContents)
        self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(7)
        for i in range(7):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget_2.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, item)
        for i in range(6):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, item)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tableWidget_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.dockWidget_2.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        MainWindow.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(2), self.dockWidget_2)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())## Heading ##
```

Comment: You do not have any QDockWidget

Comment: @eyllanesc Right - I don't know how to add one that wouldn't break up the layout I have already. If I add one using the BottomDockWidgetArea option, then I'd have 4 offset sections in a rectangular pattern instead of 3 in a square pattern, and the dock wouldn't be where I'm trying to get it. I figured it'd be easier to get help if I didn't clutter it with code that someone else would have to delete.

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you want, you confuse me with the description of your software, what parts do you want to move, and in what spaces, and what parts do not?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want the Qdockwidget to take the space of the lower right-hand corner of the main window (currently occupied by "widget_3" and populated with "tableWidget_2"). What I get instead is a Qdockwidget that takes the entire bottom space, from left to right. This prevents the list widget from properly taking the entire vertical space, from top to bottom (it's getting eaten up by the dockwidget when installed).

Comment: As I see it is impossible, there are only regions: up, down, left, and right, there are no intersections. 
there are only unions.

Comment: @eyllanesc So what I'm asking for is only possible in C++? Would there be a way for me to write some C++ code that could be ported into python?

Comment: It can not be in C ++ or in python. Where do you get that in C ++ is it possible?

Comment: @eyllanesc In the Qt documentation, the example image shows a large box (left), and two docked widgets on the right, splitting the screen vertically. Both dockwidgets appear to be closeable, and neither takes up all of the horizontal space of the window http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-dockwidgets-example.html

Comment: In the example that shows the QDockWidgets are stacked but have space restrictions, they can be left or right. But that section is not the intersection.

Comment: That's different, would you agree to publish the solution as the translation of the C++ code to python?

Comment: @eyllanesc Would you be able to show me an example of python code that could produce a window that looks like the C++ example?

Comment: @eyllanesc "would you agree to publish the solution as the translation of the C++ code to python" - Yeah, I can do that, no problem

Comment: Python2 or Python3?

Comment: @eyllanesc Python2. Version 7.14 if it matters.

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is a translation of this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-dockwidgets-example.html, so future readers can use it to make a translation from the C++ code to Python.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)

        self.createActions()
        self.createStatusBar()
        self.createDockWindows()

        self.setWindowTitle("Dock Widgets")

        self.newLetter()
        self.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(True)

    def newLetter(self):
        self.textEdit.clear()
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.textEdit.textCursor())
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.Start)
        topFrame = cursor.currentFrame()
        topFrameFormat = topFrame.frameFormat()
        topFrameFormat.setPadding(16)
        topFrame.setFrameFormat(topFrameFormat)

        textFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        boldFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        boldFormat.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        italicFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        italicFormat.setFontItalic(True)

        tableFormat = QtGui.QTextTableFormat()
        tableFormat.setBorder(1)
        tableFormat.setCellPadding(16)
        tableFormat.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        cursor.insertTable(1, 1, tableFormat)
        cursor.insertText("The Firm", boldFormat)
        cursor.insertBlock()
        cursor.insertText("321 City Street", textFormat)
        cursor.insertBlock()
        cursor.insertText("Industry Park")
        cursor.insertBlock()
        cursor.insertText("Some Country")
        cursor.setPosition(topFrame.lastPosition())
        cursor.insertText(QtCore.QDate.currentDate().toString("d MMMM yyyy"), textFormat)
        cursor.insertBlock()
        cursor.insertBlock()
        cursor.insertText("Dear ", textFormat)
        cursor.insertText("NAME", italicFormat)
        cursor.insertText(",", textFormat)

        for i in range(3): 
            cursor.insertBlock()

        cursor.insertText("Yours sincerely,", textFormat)

        for i in range(3):  
            cursor.insertBlock()

        cursor.insertText("The Boss", textFormat)
        cursor.insertBlock()
        cursor.insertText("ADDRESS", italicFormat)

    def print_(self):
        document = self.textEdit.document()
        printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
        dlg = QtGui.QPrintDialog(printer, self)
        if dlg.exec() != QtGui.QDialog.Accepted: 
            return

        document.print_(printer)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready", 2000)

    def save(self):
        fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
                        "Choose a file name", ".", "HTML document (*.html *.htm)")

        if not fileName:
            return

        file = QtCore.QFile(fileName)

        if not file.open(QtCore.QFile.WriteOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text):
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Dock Widgets",
                             "Cannot write file {}:\n{}."
                             .format(QtCore.QDir.toNativeSeparators(fileName), file.errorString()))
            return

        out = QTextStream(file)
        QtGui.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor)
        out << textEdit.toHtml()
        QtGui.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Saved '{}'".format(fileName), 2000)

    def undo(self):
        document = self.textEdit.document()
        document.undo()

    def insertCustomer(self, customer):
        if not customer:
            return
        customerList = customer.split(", ")
        document = self.textEdit.document()
        cursor = document.find("NAME")

        if not cursor.isNull():
            cursor.beginEditBlock()
            cursor.insertText(customerList[0])
            oldcursor = cursor
            cursor = document.find("ADDRESS")
            if not cursor.isNull():
                for c in customerList:
                    cursor.insertBlock()
                    cursor.insertText(c)

                cursor.endEditBlock()
            else:
                oldcursor.endEditBlock()

    def addParagraph(self, paragraph):
        if not paragraph:
            return
        document = self.textEdit.document()
        cursor = document.find("Yours sincerely,")

        if cursor.isNull():
            return

        cursor.beginEditBlock()
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.PreviousBlock, QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveAnchor, 2)
        cursor.insertBlock()
        cursor.insertText(paragraph)
        cursor.insertBlock()
        cursor.endEditBlock()

    def about(self):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "About Dock Widgets",
               "The <b>Dock Widgets</b> example demonstrates how to "
               "use Qt's dock widgets. You can enter your own text, "
               "click a customer to add a customer name and "
               "address, and click standard paragraphs to add them.")

    def createActions(self):
        fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        fileToolBar = self.addToolBar("File")

        newIcon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("document-new", QtGui.QIcon(":/images/new.png"))
        newLetterAct = QtGui.QAction(newIcon, "&New Letter", self)
        newLetterAct.setShortcuts(QtGui.QKeySequence.New)
        newLetterAct.setStatusTip("Create a new form letter")
        newLetterAct.triggered.connect(self.newLetter)
        fileMenu.addAction(newLetterAct)
        fileToolBar.addAction(newLetterAct)

        saveIcon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("document-save", QtGui.QIcon(":/images/save.png"))
        saveAct = QtGui.QAction(saveIcon, "&Save...", self)
        saveAct.setShortcuts(QtGui.QKeySequence.Save)
        saveAct.setStatusTip("Save the current form letter")
        saveAct.triggered.connect(self.save)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAct)
        fileToolBar.addAction(saveAct)

        printIcon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("document-print", QtGui.QIcon(":/images/print.png"))
        printAct = QtGui.QAction(printIcon,"&Print...", self)
        printAct.setShortcuts(QtGui.QKeySequence.Print)
        printAct.setStatusTip("Print the current form letter")
        printAct.triggered.connect(self.print_)
        fileMenu.addAction(printAct)
        fileToolBar.addAction(printAct)

        fileMenu.addSeparator()

        quitAct = fileMenu.addAction("&Quit", self.close)
        quitAct.setShortcuts(QtGui.QKeySequence.Quit)
        quitAct.setStatusTip("Quit the application")

        editMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Edit")
        editToolBar = self.addToolBar("Edit")
        undoIcon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("edit-undo", QtGui.QIcon(":/images/undo.png"))
        undoAct = QtGui.QAction(undoIcon, "&Undo", self)
        undoAct.setShortcuts(QtGui.QKeySequence.Undo)
        undoAct.setStatusTip("Undo the last editing action")
        undoAct.triggered.connect(self.undo)
        editMenu.addAction(undoAct)
        editToolBar.addAction(undoAct)

        self.viewMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&View")

        self.menuBar().addSeparator()

        helpMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Help")

        aboutAct = helpMenu.addAction("&About", self.about)
        aboutAct.setStatusTip("Show the application's About box")

        aboutQtAct = helpMenu.addAction("About &Qt", QtGui.qApp.aboutQt)
        aboutQtAct.setStatusTip("Show the Qt library's About box")

    def createStatusBar(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")

    def createDockWindows(self):
        dock = QtGui.QDockWidget("Customers", self)
        dock.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        self.customerList = QtGui.QListWidget(dock)
        self.customerList.addItems([
            "John Doe, Harmony Enterprises, 12 Lakeside, Ambleton",
            "Jane Doe, Memorabilia, 23 Watersedge, Beaton",
            "Tammy Shea, Tiblanka, 38 Sea Views, Carlton",
            "Tim Sheen, Caraba Gifts, 48 Ocean Way, Deal",
            "Sol Harvey, Chicos Coffee, 53 New Springs, Eccleston",
            "Sally Hobart, Tiroli Tea, 67 Long River, Fedula"])
        dock.setWidget(self.customerList)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock)
        self.viewMenu.addAction(dock.toggleViewAction())


        dock = QtGui.QDockWidget("Paragraphs", self)
        self.paragraphsList = QtGui.QListWidget(dock)
        self.paragraphsList.addItems([
            """Thank you for your payment which we have received today.""",
            """Your order has been dispatched and should be with you \
within 28 days.""",
            """We have dispatched those items that were in stock. The \
rest of your order will be dispatched once all the \
remaining items have arrived at our warehouse. No \
additional shipping charges will be made.""",
            """You made a small overpayment (less than $5) which we \
will keep on account for you, or return at your request.""",
            """You made a small underpayment (less than $1), but we have \
sent your order anyway. We'll add this underpayment to \
your next bill.""",
            """Unfortunately you did not send enough money. Please remit \
an additional $. Your order will be dispatched as soon as \
the complete amount has been received.""",
            """You made an overpayment (more than $5). Do you wish to \
buy more items, or should we return the excess to you?"""])

        dock.setWidget(self.paragraphsList);
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock)
        self.viewMenu.addAction(dock.toggleViewAction())

        self.customerList.currentTextChanged.connect(self.insertCustomer)
        self.paragraphsList.currentTextChanged.connect(self.addParagraph)

# import dockwidgets_rc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The complete example can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/51144569). The `.qrc` file has been compiled for Python 2 (`dockwidgets_rc.py`), but for Python 3 you must recompile the file.